# Excel sheet export to Access via ADODB inconsistent behavior

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I am experiencing an odd behavior when I'm exporting an Excel spreadsheet into a Access database via ADODB. The Office version is 2013 32bit running on Win7 64bit. These are the steps:

1. I have created a new Access file called '**test.accdb**' with just one table '**orders**' and one field '**OrderID**'. The table is empty.
2. I have created a new .csv file, **orders.csv**. Later I show the content of this file and the end result.
3. I have an Excel addin with the following macro:

   ```
   Public Sub updateAccess()

   Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim connectionString As String
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim sql As String
   Dim Filename As String

   Filename = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.accdb"

   connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" & Filename
   connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Filename

   Call con.Open(connectionString)

   sql = "DELETE FROM orders"
   Call con.Execute(sql)

   sql = "INSERT INTO orders " & _
         "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & _
         ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "].[" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "$]"
   Set rs = con.Execute(sql)

   Call con.Close
   Set con = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```
4. I then open the **order.csv** file using Excel, run the macro and then open **test.accdb** using Access. Depending on the content of the csv file, different results are output:

**Case A**

orders.csv:

```
OrderID
1
A
```

test.accdb, in table 'orders':

```
OrderID
1
A
```

**Case B**

orders.csv:

```
OrderID
1
A
3
```

test.accdb, in table 'orders'

```
OrderID
<blank>
1
3
```

**Case C**

orders.csv:

```
OrderID
1
A
3
B
C
D
```

test.accdb, in table 'orders'

```
OrderID
1
3
A
B
C
D
```

Why is case B failing?

I can't wrap my head around it. I tried two drivers, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADODB with an Excel database will guess the field types from the first 16 records. In the case

```
OrderID
1
A
3
```

it will guess numeric field type since numeric is in majority.

To avoid this, you can use the `IMEX` parameter within the connection string, see: https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

So with your code:

```
...
sql = "INSERT INTO orders " & _
      "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE=" & _
      ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "].[" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "$]"
Set rs = con.Execute(sql)
...
```